# DRF failing when content type = json

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am using Django Rest Framework with an angularJS application and it works fine. However, when I try using python requests to communicate to any of its endpoints I get an error whenever I set the Content-Type = "application/json". Here's an example:

```
import requests
res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={
    "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token_json['access'],
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
})

# And in my django view
path = request.data['path']
```

> {'detail': 'JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}

However, as soon as I remove the `Content-Type: application/json` line, things start working -- though my json isn't properly passed (for example, `2` is passed as the string `"2"` instead of the number `2`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `json` parameter, which has been available since [version 2.4.2](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

An example would be:

```
import requests
res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={
    "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token_json['access']
})
```

Notice how we're setting `json=data` instead of `data=data`, and omitting the `Content-Type` header. It automatically encodes the python object you pass using `json.dumps`, and also sets the correct Content-Type header for you too.